# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.' in da.Fill(dt)

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, ado.net, oledb

I'm doing this thing in C# Windows Form where it counts rows by group in Access Database and displays the total number of that group in `dataGridview`. But when I run it, I get a message that says:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.' on the da.Fill(dt);

This is my code `BrandName` is the name of the field from my table `tblmain`.

```
md = new OleDbCommand("SELECT BrandName, COUNT(BrandName) AS Quantity FROM tblmain GROUP BY BrandName HAVING (COUNT(BrandName)>= 1) ORDER BY Quantity DESC", con);      
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dgvQuantity.DataSource = dt;
```

Or can anyone recommend an alternative way to get the count of a row by group in Access Database and display it in `datagridview`
like in this picture

[image]

Comment: I presume there is a typo here and `md` should be `cmd`?

Comment: Please show your table schema. And have you tried: `SELECT BrandName, COUNT(BrandName) AS Quantity FROM tblmain GROUP BY BrandName HAVING (COUNT(BrandName)>= 1) ORDER BY COUNT(BrandName) DESC`?

Answer (score 1):

Would say the `QUANTITY` in the `ORDER BY` was treated as a column in the table and this column did not exist. But, it is a column alias for `COUNT(BrandName)` which you need to perform sorting based on the value.

You should use `COUNT(BrandName)` (the aggregate function) in `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT BrandName, COUNT(BrandName) AS Quantity 
FROM tblmain 
GROUP BY BrandName 
HAVING COUNT(BrandName)>= 1
ORDER BY COUNT(BrandName) DESC
```